# How to add directories into build path for latex workshop vs code plugin?

Tags: pdftex, random

I'm using latex workshop in VS code on Windows and I have the following issue. So I have my bibliography in `./bibliography` folder, my figures in `./figures` folder and styles in `./styles` folder and all my tex files in the root directory. I need pdflatex to check those other folders too when compiling but none of the builtin recipes does that. I tried changing `latex-workshop.latex.tools` in `settings.json` with this:

```
{
    "name": "pdflatex",
    "command": "pdflatex",
    "args": [
        "--shell-escape", // if you want to have the shell-escape flag
        "-synctex=1",
        "-interaction=nonstopmode",
        "-file-line-error",
        "-aux-directory=styles",
        "%DOC%"
    ]
}
```

But this is a very hacky way of doing it and not good for when I change folder names. Also bibtex still doesn't work with this hack. Anyone has this figured out?

Comment: TeX uses environment (there are a few MiKTeX specific) but .sty files have many preferred folders see texinputs= or texmf variables (beware seperators : for nix ; for windows there are others each for bibinputs and bst files and you can also use \graphicspath{{./figures/}{second}{third}{etc}}

Comment: @KJO thank you that solved my issue. I added the texmf in my env and it seems to be working just fine now.